# Let admins sort products in a template arbitrary

Tags: magento-1.8, sorting

I want to let the admin of a Magento site I'm developing to sort the products in a category arbitrary, this is that Magento shouldn't order them by price, name or anything else. Ideally, the admin would see a list of products and drag n' drop products to sort them.

The best approach I could think of is to create a custom numeric attribute and then sort by that attribute on the template file, but that would be pretty annoying for the user. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the position attribute in the category admin. Check the attached image.[image: position]

Comment: Nice! Do you know of an extension that would simplify the work for my client with sth like Drag n' Drop?

Comment: I have never seen something like that, but it might exist. With a quick search i found this, but its a paid extension (i didnt made it): http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/drag-drop-sort-products.html